# How to get response from server using volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-json

I am using volley to get Json data from server. This is a detect language API which accepts text and API key as parameters. When i send the request the response from the API is that "the key is invalid." I have checked it on postman and the key works fine.

here is my code.

```
public void detectlanguage(Context context, final String str) {


    String url = String.format("http://ws.detectlanguage.com/0.2/detect");


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    res = response.toString();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
                        Log.i((TAG), jsonObject.toString());
                        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("detections");
                        string = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("language");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(TakePicture.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
     {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(2);
            params.put("q", str);
            params.put("key", key);

            return params;
        }

         @Override
         public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

             final HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
             headers.put("Content-Type", "form-data;boundary=" + BOUNDARY);
             return headers;


         }
     };


    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, TAG);


}
```

The code worked when i manually appended the data but its not working this way. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void detectlanguage(Context context, final String str) {


String url = String.format("http://ws.detectlanguage.com/0.2/detect");

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try{
   jsonObject.put("first_name", "S");
   jsonObject.put("last_name", "K");   
}

catch(Exception e)
{}

//3rd Parms not null if your have parms
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject,
        new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                res = response.toString();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
                    Log.i((TAG), jsonObject.toString());
                    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("detections");
                    string = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("language");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(TakePicture.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
})
 {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(2);
        params.put("q", str);
        params.put("key", key);

        return params;
    }

     @Override
     public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

         final HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
         headers.put("Content-Type", "form-data;boundary=" + BOUNDARY);
         return headers;
     }
 };
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, TAG);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what are you trying to do here?

Comment: r u sending parameters with url or not??

Comment: yes i am, the response i am getting from the server is "Invalid Api key", but the key works fine with postman.

Comment: what process you are doing on post man can u tell me. then i can solve ur problem

Comment: I am adding the parameters in the body of the url.

Comment: first if ur method post then have to send jsonobject not send in url